# How to reposition object on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, html5-canvas, webgl

The issue I am having is as follows:

If I refresh the page, my object will be positioned in a certain way and when I resize the window, my object will be resized and positioned correctly. However, if I refresh the page after I resized the window, my object will be positioned incorrectly.

My code is below:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  var scene, camera, renderer , controls, ambientLight, pointLight, textureLoader, map, material, loader, container;
  var canvas = $('#canvas');

  function init() {
      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      initChris();
      initCamera();
      initRenderer();
      initControl();
      render();
  }

  function initCamera() {
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 3600);
      ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.4 );
      pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
      camera.position.set(0, 0, 1800);
      camera.add( pointLight );
      scene.add( camera );
      scene.add( ambientLight );
      camera.lookAt(scene.position);
  }

  function initRenderer() {
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
      renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
      renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
      renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
  }

  function initControl(){
      controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
      controls.enableZoom  = false;
      controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.5;
      controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.5;
      controls.update();
  }

  function initChris() {
    textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    map = textureLoader.load('img/CHRIS.jpg');
    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: map});
    loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    loader.load( 'obj/CHRIS.obj', function ( object ) {
      object.traverse( function ( node ) {
        if ( node.isMesh ){
          node.material = material;
        }
      });
      object.position.y = - (window.innerHeight / 2) - 400;
      scene.add( object );
    });
  }

  function onWindowResize(){
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  }

  function render() {
      canvas.append(renderer.domElement);
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
  }

  init();
});
```

I believe the issue I am facing is related to object.position.y = - (window.innerHeight / 2) - 400; and when it gets triggered.

If I take out object.position.y = - (window.innerHeight / 2) - 400; then i get a consistent behaviour when I reload and resize the page, however the position of my model is wrong. I need my object to be consistently aligned to the bottom of the page.

Any advise is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're only setting the position within `initChris()` and not `onWindowResize()`. If you want to see both behaving the same, you'll need to do something like this:

```
// Init variable outside of functions to place it in global scope.
var chris;

function initChris() {
    // ...

    loader.load( 'obj/CHRIS.obj', function ( object ) {
        object.traverse( function ( node ) {
            if ( node.isMesh ){
                node.material = material;
            }
        });

      // Assign a value to chris so it's
      // accessible from outside this function
      chris = object;
      updatePositionChris();
      scene.add( object );
    });
}

function onWindowResize(){
    // ...
    updatePositionChris();
}

function updatePositionChris() {
    chris.position.y = - (window.innerHeight / 2) - 400;
}
```

Declaring `var chris;` outside the functions sets its scope so it can be accessed inside those functions. Then you have to call `updatePositionChris()` both when it's loaded, and when the window resizes so both events behave the same way.